# Unwanted "Enter" character is adding while page load or page posts back

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, bootstrapping

I am facing one unusual problem from so many days.
I have one project in asp.net. Using vb.net for code.
We have used bootstrap for design purpose as well.
The problem is wherever I have used the text area in page and when that page loads, The "Enter" automatically comes in it. I am showing remaining characters below the text area. 
For example assume there are 50 characters to enter. and when page loads and I focus to text area, the remaining characters value become one less i.e 49 here. Because one "Enter" character is there. Not getting this at all. I have debugged the code. When page rendering finish and page appears, this happens.
The image is here how it looks[image]
For now When I save the text, I have removed this character. But I wanted to fix it permanently.
Is that any issue because of bootstrap? Not getting this.
Please any suggestions / solutions on this

Thank you

Comment: Update your question with your HTML for your textarea and any associated JavaScript.

Comment: Hello Sir,
I have updated my question. Please review it once

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unwanted “Enter” character is adding while page load or page posts back : Updated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996354/unwanted-enter-character-is-adding-while-page-load-or-page-posts-back-update)