# Unwanted “Enter” character is adding while page load or page posts back : Updated

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, bootstrapping

I am facing one unusual problem from so many days. I have one project in asp.net. Using vb.net for code. We have used bootstrap for design purpose as well. The problem is wherever I have used the text area in page and when that page loads, The "Enter" automatically comes in it. I am showing remaining characters below the text area. For example assume there are 50 characters to enter. and when page loads and I focus to text area, the remaining characters value become one less i.e 49 here. Because one "Enter" character is there. Not getting this at all. I have debugged the code. When page rendering finish and page appears, this happens. The image is here how it looks
[image]
For now When I save the text, I have removed this character. But I wanted to fix it permanently. Is that any issue because of bootstrap? Not getting this. Please any suggestions / solutions on this

Here is the script to calculate remaining characters:

```
function AddFact() {
        if (parseInt(document.getElementById("ctl00_content_txtFact").value.length) <= 250) {
            document.getElementById("ctl00_content_lblCharCnt").innerText = (250 - document.getElementById("ctl00_content_txtFact").value.length);
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("ctl00_content_txtFact").value = document.getElementById("ctl00_content_txtFact").value.substring(0, 250);
        }
    }
```

Here is the script below to prevent the special characters from to be entered:

```
function valid(f) {
        if ((/[^a-zA-Z0-9_@!',.&? \n-]/g).test(f.value)) {
            f.value = f.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_@!',.&? \n-]/g, '');
            document.getElementById("ctl00_content_lblErrMsg").innerText = "Special Characters are not allowed";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("ctl00_content_lblErrMsg").innerText = "";
            null;
        }
    }
```

Here is my HTML text area code :

```
<td width="25%" align="left" class="label2" style="vertical-align: top">&nbsp;Add <u>F</u>act</td>
                            <td width="60%" valign="top" align="left" class="label2"><asp:TextBox ID="txtFact" Rows="6" Columns="50" AccessKey="F" onKeyup="AddFact()" onKeyDown="valid(this)" runat="server" style="width: 300px" TextMode="MultiLine" TabIndex="11" />
                                <br /> Characters Left :
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCharCnt" runat="server" Text="500"></asp:Label>
                                <br />
                                <br />
                            </td>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: do you have a working model hosted?

Comment: Yes...I have that

Comment: give the link. Let me give a try

Comment: Okay, Go to link below:
https://www.iquriouskids.com/addbusiness/us/texas/houston

Enter "American Robotics Academy" into "Provider Name" text box
Then one little form will appear in front of you.
at the end, there is one text area. You will see the "Enter" character already present inside the box as it loads

see it and let me know.
Thank you for your reply

Comment: I casted an upvote to make you 20+ Rep.(required to participate in chat). Come on chat. I need more details. There are errors in your page

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138937/room-for-sagar-v-and-devdan-gaikwad